# Relating two models through associated foreign keys with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, associations, relationship

I'm having trouble setting up my relationships and queries.  Here is a simple explaination of what I want to accomplish.  Say I have three models:  Drawings, Changes, and Revisions.

A Drawing has many Revisions

A Change has many Revisions

A Change has many drawings through revisions

The Drawings have fields for primary key as well as a string: `drawing_number` that is unique to each Drawing.

When I create a new `Change`, I have a nested form that creates new Revisions within the Change.  I would like to have one of the fields in the new Revision be the `drawing_number` even though the foreign key is the `drawing_id`.  Is there a way to set it up so that I enter the `drawing_number` in the form, it then finds the `drawing_id` that matches that `drawing_number`, and adds that `drawing_id` into the drawing_id column in the Revisions table.

In other words, I want to relate the Revisions to the Drawings using an associated field that is not the foreign key.

For example:  I have drawing_id = 7 and drawing_number = A7114B1

I create a new Change which has a Revision form nested in it.  I enter drawing_number A7114B1 into the form, but the Revision model only has a drawing_id column, not a drawing_number column.  I would like the logic to find the drawing_id that matches the drawing_number, and place the drawing_id into the Revisions table.

Comment: Do you have both drawing_id and drawing_number, or only one of it?

Comment: Revisions contains the foreign key drawing_id.  It does not contain drawing_number.  The field drawing_number is only located in the Drawings model

Comment: You could indeed set it up so that you can enter the drawing number and fill in information based upon `drawing_id` after looking up the cross-reference. When you enter the drawing number and submit the form, the controller could do the lookup and provide the information back to the view.

Answer (score 1):

## Assuming `drawing_number` == `drawing_id`

If I understood well, your data is already correctly modeled, but you want an alias to your attribute name on `Drawing`. This can be done with [`#alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute):

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :drawing_number, :drawing_id
end
```

Now you can use `drawing_number` as an attribute exactly the way you would do with `drawing_id`, like:

```
> Drawing.where(drawing_id: 1) == Drawing.where(drawing_number: 1)
 => true
```

## Assuming `drawing_number` != `drawing_id`

I'm assuming that `Drawing` have the attribute `number` and `Revision` have the attribute `drawing_number`, both as strings. You need to manually set foreign_key and primary_key of the associations, like the following:

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, foreign_key: :drawing_number, primary_key: :number
end

cass Change < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions
end

class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drawing, foreign_key: :drawing_number
  belongs_to :change
end
```

Comment: This may not work out if the format/range of `drawing number` is something defined by the OP's configuration management requirements.

Comment: @mbratch you are correct, I'm assuming that drawing_number is an integer (the actual drawing_id)

Comment: No, drawing_number is a string defined by the user.  I have validations in place to ensure that it is unique, but it will be an alphanumeric string.

Comment: @SteveAbrams edited my answer to reflect that - so the problem is a database modeling one, correct?

Comment: @fotanus, I believe your answer will work.  My goal, however, is to not manually change and define any of the keys.  I would like use the default drawing_id:integer as the foreign key in Revisions, and have the drawing_number:string attribute only in Drawings.  The user will only know the drawing_number string, so I don't want any users to be referencing the primary keys in any forms. I would like the controller or model to find which drawing_id I'm looking for based on the drawing attribute drawing_number.

Comment: @SteveAbrams maybe you are looking for [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) ?